# Input elements not being posted with HTML5

Tags: forms, html, post

I'm working on a test HTML5 login form and have the form set up like so:

```
<form id="login" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>   
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit_data" value="Log in">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When clicking Submit, the form is posted back to the same page.  When I print the array of POSTed elements, I'm only seeing one for 'submit_data'.   'username' and 'password' are not coming through.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified names for your inputs, e.g.

```
<form id="login" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>   
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit_data" value="Log in">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

That might fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks -- easy fix to an oversight on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just perform a check for isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']) instead of the print_r (which I assume you are using)?

```
<input type="..." NAME="username" ..>  You haven't set var name.
```

Also instead of placeholder, set value="Username" and value="Password".  There may not be any value passed if just using placeholder.  See this test:  http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder

As you submit without anything, no value is passed.  Once you type something in, value is passed.

Comment: If posting an element with an empty value... like <input name="myval" value=""> you will still receive a POST/GET array element of 'myval' it will just be empty.  IF you add DISABLED to the input element, then the element will not be passed and you won't see it in the post/get array.